# How can I show these 3 query result in one table in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
WHILE @i <= @stsem
BEGIN
    SELECT
        SUM(sb.totalmarks) AS Sub_total,
        SUM(sb.credit) AS Credit_total, 
        SUM(a.totalmarks) AS Total_obt, 
        SUM(a.rankpoint) AS RP_total,
        (SUM(rankpoint) / SUM(sb.credit)) AS SGPA,
        @i AS Sem  
    FROM
        umms.dbo.[dt_result] AS a 
    JOIN
        umms.dbo.[dt_subjectdetails] AS sb ON a.paperid = sb.paperid  
    WHERE
        studentid = 17780 
        AND btid = 495 
        AND a.semid = @i  
        AND (grade != 'F' OR grade != 'Ab' OR grade != 'IN')
              
    IF @i = 10
        BREAK; 

    SET @i = @i + 1;
END;

SELECT SUM(b.credit) as TotalCredit,SUM(rankpoint) as TotalGradepoint ,(SUM(rankpoint)/SUM(b.credit)) as CGPA FROM umms.dbo.[dt_result] as a join umms.dbo.[dt_subjectdetails] as b on a.paperid=b.paperid where studentid=17780 and btid=495
```

This query executes 3 times.

[image]

Comment: `grade != 'F' OR grade != 'Ab' OR grade != 'IN'` looks pretty suspect, I think the logic is wrong and you probably want `grade != 'F' AND grade != 'Ab' AND grade != 'IN'` or `grade NOT IN ('F', 'Ab', 'IN')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a simple filter on `a.semid` and a `GROUP BY` on the same column should do the trick:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(sb.totalmarks) AS Sub_total,
    SUM(sb.credit) AS Credit_total, 
    SUM(a.totalmarks) AS Total_obt, 
    SUM(a.rankpoint) AS RP_total,
    (SUM(rankpoint) / SUM(sb.credit)) AS SGPA,
    a.semid AS Sem  
FROM
    umms.dbo.[dt_result] AS a 
JOIN
    umms.dbo.[dt_subjectdetails] AS sb ON a.paperid = sb.paperid  
WHERE
    studentid = 17780 
    AND btid = 495 
    AND a.semid >= 1 AND a.semid <= 10  
    AND (grade != 'F' OR grade != 'Ab' OR grade != 'IN')
GROUP BY
    a.semid;
```

The second query could potentially be combined also, by using a `ROLLUP`, but the `grade` and `semid` filters make this more difficult.

> The logic `grade != 'F' OR grade != 'Ab' OR grade != 'IN'` appears incorrect. I suggest you take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to need a loop here, try this instead

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        RN = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        RN = RN +1
        FROM CTE
            WHERE RN <10
)
SELECT
    SUM(sb.totalmarks) AS Sub_total,
    SUM(sb.credit) AS Credit_total, 
    SUM(a.totalmarks) AS Total_obt, 
    SUM(a.rankpoint) AS RP_total,
    (SUM(rankpoint) / SUM(sb.credit)) AS SGPA,
    CTE.RN AS Sem  
    FROM
        umms.dbo.[dt_result] AS a 
    JOIN
        umms.dbo.[dt_subjectdetails] AS sb ON a.paperid = sb.paperid  
    JOIN CTE 
        ON a.semid = CTE.RN
    WHERE
        studentid = 17780 
        AND btid = 495  
        AND (grade != 'F' OR grade != 'Ab' OR grade != 'IN')
    GROUP BY 
        CTE.RN
```